# SQL command token unknown error

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to update some values on a table, I need to change the values to be more specific.

I tried the command, but it's only works if I try one by one.

```
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '53'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '2'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '53'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '75'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '77'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '79'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '53'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '101'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '103'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '53'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '149'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '169'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '53'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '173'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '175'
update impostos_perfil set sit_trib_ipi_sai = '51'where sit_trib_ipi_sai = '99'and perfil_imposto = '177'
```

I´m using IBX expert to manage my server base, and when I try to update all at once, appears this error:
[image: IBX ERROR]

Comment: SQL statements need to be terminated with `;` - at least in standard SQL. Not sure what an "*IBX expert server base*" is.

Comment: By the looks of it, you are using Firebird or Interbase, not SQL Server. Also, AFAIK, you are using IB Expert, not IBX Expert (IBX is a connectivity library).